# CSS button breaks in Safari 8 but is fine in Chrome, FF, IE

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

We have a couple of buttons used in our site's front page. My CSS-fu is admittedly terrible so I sourced the button CSS from an online button generator and modified it to our tastes.

This button looks fine in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (former two tested on OS X) but breaks apart on Safari 8 on Yosemite. I've isolated the target HTML and CSS in jsfiddle to verify: http://jsfiddle.net/0njbe8v5/

Snippet of the CSS in question:

```
.lander-btn, .lander-profile-btn {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background-color:#ededed;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#777777;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}

.lander-btn {
    width: 400px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: -10px 0px;
    line-height:  90px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.lander-btn:hover {
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}

.lander-btn:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.lander-btn img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.lander-btn-txt {
    width:290px;
}
```

I've tried toggling rules in the inspector in Safari to no effect. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It looks like it's ignoring the `display:flex`. You could reworking it with a different display

Comment: That's it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction - in Safari flex requires the webkit prefix per here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

are you using this tag

```
<button>
```

opposed to this tag

```
<input type = "submit"> tag?
```

This could be an issue

Comment: Elaborate please? Using classes or...?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems (for Safari at least) on a button element you need to explicitly define the flex-flow as row or column if you're trying to center both axis values.

Granted Safari should be defaulting to "row", but it I guess it ignores it on a button element for some reason.